# Функция указанная в onClick() выполняется два раза, при условии что указана всего один раз

Tags: c#, unity3d

Код вызываемой кнопкой функции

```
 public void PickUpWeapon()
        {
            print("click");
            if (gun!=null) OnWeaponPickup(gun);
            if (currentWeapon != -1) RemoveWeaponInCurrentSlot();
        }
```

Функция фигурирует только в OnClick() определённой кнопки
[image: скриншот поля OnClick в Инспекторе]

При запуске игры и при нажатии на данную UI кнопку сообщение ***"click"*** прилетает два раза, соответственно и код выполняется два раза. Первый раз при нажатии, и после при нажатии в абсолютно любую точку **Canvas**

В чём может быть причина? Нигде больше данная функция не указана.

Comment: https://forum.unity.com/threads/button-onclick-event-is-firing-twice.359933/

Answer (score -1):

Решение "двойного касания"

Необходимо убрать ***mouse0*** из всех осей (в которых имеется) в *Input* **(Edit - Project Settings - Input)**